# What do the character stats mean?

Tags: anime-studio-story

Your characters have a set of stats that you can increase each time they level up, but I'm not sure what they mean or how it relates to the anime I am developing.

What does each stat do and how does it relate to anime productions (if at all)?

the stats the character you add to your shows are *Courage, Humor, Amity, Cuteness,* and *oddness*.

I kind of figured they'd play some part in the character awards that happen (cute characters are more dateable?), but as for the shows themselves, I have no idea what each stat influences.

Comment: It's not as cut and dry as earlier games since there isn't predefined stages where a particular stat is implied (ala magazine mogul). I honestly haven't figured it out myself; I have a level 5 exec producer, which is apparently the "ultimate class" in the game, and she writes scripts about as well as my normal starter director. I'd hazard a guess that the stats just affect the amount and frequency that the related attribute in the currently worked project will proc. But that's just a guess.

Comment: not employee stats, *character* stats, as in the ones you add to your show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character's stats will determine what merchandise offer they get.

For example, high courage will get you a video game offer, whilst cuteness gets a plushie or phone strap offer.

They will tell you which stat make them offer you the specific offer the first time they come to the office, after that you just got notification about the offer on your side panel.